# adding elements to Hashmap

Tags: java, java-8

```
public class Osoba {
  final  String imie;
  final    String nazwisko;

    public Osoba(String imie, String nazwisko) {
        this.imie = imie;
        this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.imie);
        hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.nazwisko);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Osoba other = (Osoba) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.imie, other.imie)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.nazwisko, other.nazwisko)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return imie+" "+nazwisko; //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }



public class Pracownik extends Osoba{
private String stanowisko;
private double pensja;
    public Pracownik(String imie, String nazwisko) {
        super(imie, nazwisko);
    }



    public String getStanowisko() {
        return stanowisko;
    }

    public double getPensja() {
        return pensja;
    }

    public String getImie() {
        return imie;
    }

    public String getNazwisko() {
        return nazwisko;
    }

    public void setPensja(double pensja) {
        this.pensja = pensja;
    }

    public void setStanowisko(String stanowisko) {
        this.stanowisko = stanowisko;
    }




    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString()+" "+stanowisko+" "+pensja; //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

    }


public class Firma{
   Set<Pracownik> spis=new HashSet<Pracownik>() {};

   public void init(){
       Pracownik a1=new Pracownik("Iks","Iksinski");
       Pracownik a2 = new Pracownik("Maria", "Nowak"); 
       spis.add(a1);
       spis.add(a2);
       spis.add(new Pracownik("A","Aski"));
        for(Iterator it=spis.iterator();it.hasNext();)
        System.out.print(it.toString());
   }

}

 public static void zadanie4(){
         Firma ob=new Firma();
       ob.init();

    }
```

result of init() java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator@15db9742java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator@15db9742java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator@15db9742java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator@15db9742ja...

and I don't understand why it doesn't show me proper result

Comment: `it.next().toString()` if you want to apply `toString()` on the current element of the iteration.

Comment: You should also declare generic Iterator : `Iterator<Pracownik>` instead of raw Iterator : `Iterator` (even it to apply the toString() method you may not see the advantage of it).

Answer (score 0):

You should call `it.next()`, which would return the next element of the `Set`, and print that element (instead of printing the `Iterator` instance as you currently do):

```
for (Iterator<Pracownik> it=spis.iterator();it.hasNext();)
    System.out.print(it.next().toString());
```

P.S., you should use a generic `Iterator<Pracownik>` instead of the raw `Iterator`, so that `it.next()` will return a `Pracownik` reference instead of an `Object` reference.

Comment: Of course, whenever possible, not dealing with an `Iterator` manually is the better option: `for(Pracownik p: spis) System.out.println(p);`

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code :- 
You are calling The `toString()` method of Iterator Class.
Which is an interface and doesn't have any implementation of `toSting()` method of `Object` Class.

So `Itrator.toString()` method will call the `toString()` method of Object class.

Please find the implementation `toString()` method of Object class Which Clearly Return the `ClassName+HaxCode` of Callie object.
you are calling Please find the attached code.

```
public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(this.hashCode());
    }
```

You need to use Iterator's  `E next();` method to print the results.
As your USED collection HashSet has override the `E next();` of iterator interface as bellow.

```
public ListIterator<E> listIterator(final int index) {
        final ListIterator<E> i = list.listIterator(index);

        return new ListIterator<E>() {
            public boolean hasNext()     { return i.hasNext(); }
            public E next()              { return i.next(); }
            public boolean hasPrevious() { return i.hasPrevious(); }
            public E previous()          { return i.previous(); }
         };   
    }
```

So in your code you should use Collections Overridden `next()` method which will return the value of collection instead of calling the `Itreators.toString()` method.
[image]